# Spark execution - Relationship between spark execution job and spark action

Tags: apache-spark

I have one question regarding Spark execution which .

We all know that Each spark application (or the driver program) may contain one or many actions.

My question is which one is correct - Do a collection of jobs correspond to one action OR Does each job correspond to one action. Here job means the one that can be seen in the Spark execution UI.

I think the latter is true (each job correspond to one action). Please validate

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

**Each action in spark corresponds to a Spark Job**. And these actions are called by the driver program in the application.

And therefore an action can involve many transformation on the dataset(or RDD). Which creates stages in the job.

A stage can be thought of as the set of calculations(tasks) that can each be computed on an executor without communication with other executors or with the driver.

In other words, a new stage begins whenever network travel between workers is required; for example in a shuffle. These dependencies that create stage boundaries are called ShuffleDependencies.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and your time.

Comment: I think the last two paragraphs are also mentioned in 'High Performance Spark (Best Practices for Scaling and Optimizing Apache Spark)' book.